# How to list all posible ways to concatenate a list of strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator, string-concatenation

**I want to list all possible ways to concatenate a list of strings, example:**

Input:

```
strings = ['hat','bag','cab']
```

Output:

```
concatenated = ['hatbag','hatcab','hatbagcab','hatcabbag','baghat','bagcab',
                'baghatcab','bagcabhat','cabhat','cabbag','cabhatbag','cabbaghat']
```

**I've tried using for loops for this simple 3 string list, but I can't figure out how to do it with many strings in the list.**  

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great case for the `itertools` module. You're looking for permutations of the original entries of the list, which you can get with `itertools.permutations()`. This returns a tuple, so you'll have to `join` them together. Finally, you have to tell `permutations()` how many words to choose, which in our case is "at least 2 and not more than the number of words in the list."

Since this is Python, it can all be done with one list comprehension :D

```py
>>> from itertools import permutations

>>> strings = ['hat','bag','cab']
>>> [''.join(s) for i in range(2,len(strings)+1) for s in permutations(strings,i)]
['hatbag',
 'hatcab',
 'baghat',
 'bagcab',
 'cabhat',
 'cabbag',
 'hatbagcab',
 'hatcabbag',
 'baghatcab',
 'bagcabhat',
 'cabhatbag',
 'cabbaghat']
```

In case the list comprehension is confusing, this is what it would look like if we wrote it with `for` loops.

```py
>>> from itertools import permutations

>>> strings = ['hat','bag','cab']
>>> concats = []
>>> for i in range(2, len(strings)+1):
...     for s in permutations(strings, i):
...         concats.append(''.join(s))
...
>>> concats
['hatbag',
 'hatcab',
 'baghat',
 'bagcab',
 'cabhat',
 'cabbag',
 'hatbagcab',
 'hatcabbag',
 'baghatcab',
 'bagcabhat',
 'cabhatbag',
 'cabbaghat']
```